# average, count, group by in select query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am developing a booking engine web app.
Once an user made a booking it goes to this table.

```
id  | Promo_code | total | arrival_date | departure_date | booked_date
1   | ABC1       | 1000  | 2019-02-06   | 2019-02-10     | 2019-02-02
2   | ABC1       | 2500  | 2019-02-07   | 2019-02-11     | 2019-02-03
3   | ABC1       | 3000  | 2019-02-12   | 2019-02-15     | 2019-02-03
4   | ABC2       | 5000  | 2019-02-07   | 2019-02-11     | 2019-02-02
5   | null       | 3000  | 2019-02-12   | 2019-02-15     | 2019-02-01
```

Here the promo_code is what it names implies. If the user doesn't book with a promo_code it is null (5th record).
Hope other fields total, arrival_date, departure_date and booked_date are clear to you.

My question is I want to generate a report something like this.

```
promo_code | number_of_bookings | revenue | Average_length_of_stay | Average_depart_date | Average_reservation_revenue
ABC1       | 3                  | 6500    | 3                      | 5                   | 2166
ABC2       | 1                  | 5000    | 4                      | 5                   | 5000
```

This report is called revenue by promo code report.

If I explain what happend in this report is

Average_length_of_stay = (departure_date - arrival_date) / number_of_bookings

Average_depart_date = (departure_date - booked_date) / number_of_bookings

Of cause I could generate this report by the backend logic somehow. But I would be very painful. There must be a way to query this
in the SQL directly.

What I have done upto now is

```
SELECT promo_code ,count(*) as number_of_bookings,
sum(total) as revenue
FROM booking_widget.User_packages group by promo_code;
```

I am stuck with Average_length_of_stay, Average_depart_date and Average_reservation_revenue.
How do I get the average values which the group by clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is trivial:

```
SELECT promo_code
     , COUNT(*) AS number_of_bookings
     , SUM(total) AS revenue
     , AVG(DATEDIFF(departure_date, arrival_date)) AS average_length_of_stay
     , AVG(DATEDIFF(departure_date, booked_date)) AS average_depart_date
     , AVG(total) AS average_reservation_revenue
FROM t
GROUP BY promo_code
```